# Copying one column data to other column in json format

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I am working on migration of one application. It has postgres database version 9.4.19. There is one table lets say StudentData. Earlier it has 4 columns i.e. Id, Name, Class, City. Now i have created one column i.e. "Info", which stores name, class and city in json format like this

```json
{
  "STUDENT_NAME":["Tom","Sam","Mark"],
  "STUDENT_CLASS":[3,6,2],
  "STUDENT_CITY":["Newyork","London","London"]
}
```

Now i will store any new incoming data in this json format but before deploying this new structure i want to migrate existing columns(mention above) data to new column in the json structure. I need some kind of script or sql functions. I am very weak in sql scripts.

How do it? Please help me.

EDIT: Thanks everyone for your valuable comments but i solved it by myself without using any json functions. I have done it manually by writen one cte and then update the column by manually putting json structure.

Comment: So, you want to replace your entire table structure with one single JSON object? Why do want to do this? This has only drawbacks: Create, Delete, Replace operations are very hard to do, Searching as well, Indexing is not possible, ... If you need data in this format, think about a view or something, but keep your table normalized.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry my bad. It is 9.4.19

Comment: @S-Man i already implemented it. I just need to migrate the data.

Answer (score 0):

I see few function to get the output in json (json_agg & row_t_json) and tried to use it to get similar output. Please see if this is what you are looking for:
[image]

Query for Reference:

```
with student as 
(
select 'Tom' as Name, 3 as Class, 'New York' as City union all
select 'Sam' as Name, 6 as Class, 'London' as City union all
select 'Mark' as Name, 2 as Class, 'London' as City 
)

select 
row_to_json(st_j) out_json
from
(
 select 
  json_agg(st.name) Student_Name, 
  json_agg(st.Class) Student_Class, 
  json_agg(st.City) Student_City
 from 
  student st
) st_j
```

Fiddle URL :
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=73dd0699461c8c2992e0d49da044fca3

Note: No knowledge in PostgreSQL, so there might be a better way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i need to select data from column instead of hardcoding it. For example- select data from name column, class column and city column and then create a json structure from it.

Comment: The with part is for reference. Just use the select query. Replace student table and columns with yours.

Comment: I can not use json functions because the type of column is text and i can not change it(decided by some other person).

Comment: I am doing something like this. Please see below;

Comment: WITH migrate_data AS (
SELECT name,class,city AS data FROM StudentData
)
SELECT migrate_data
UPDATE StudentData AS st SET st.info=("{'"STUDENT_NAME'":[",migrate_data.name,"]}"));